# Move label up to input

Tags: html, css, sass

I need to create an input where label goes up when input is focus/active.

[image: Example]

This is the html structure, and i can NOT modify it.

```
<div class="form-field">
  <label> Address </label>
<input class="form-input"/>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this without move Label below input element?

Comment: You can't. Current CSS can only select to the right or downwards in the DOM, not upwards or to the left.

Comment: Thanks for answer @CBroe. Do you have any doc to read about it?

Comment: You can achieve this with `:focus-within`

Comment: @Ash and, in case it is active?

Comment: you should add a `for` attribute to link your label with the input. Otherwise it's not really a  label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) pseudo-class will provide the outcome you are seeking. From the MDN docs linked previously:

> The :focus-within CSS pseudo-class matches an element if the element or any of its descendants are focused. In other words, it represents an element that is itself matched by the :focus pseudo-class or has a descendant that is matched by :focus. (This includes descendants in shadow trees.)

Here is a rough example showing the display change when a descendant of `.form-field` is given focus. This could be improved with more care taken as to the use of the `:focus-within` selector and perhaps better alignment and animation of the label itself, but nevertheless demonstrates the approach,

```css
.form-field:focus-within {
  /* allows label to be absolute */
  position: relative;
}

.form-field:focus-within label {
  position: absolute;
  /* following values might need adjustment based on existing styles and desired outcome */
  top: -0.5em;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: white;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.form-field:focus-within input {
  /* adjust to suit */
  padding: 8px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-field">
  <label> Address </label>
  <input class="form-input" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```css
.form-field:focus-within label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0.125rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-field">
  <label> Address </label>
  <input class="form-input" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ":focus-within" work nice for me. Thank for your question and the answers. This questions is kind of basic, but very helpful.
you also need:

- required: attribute inside the input html.
- pseudo: focus + valid in css to hanlde position after you fill the input.
  Can check it here.

  ```css
  body {
    background-color: #00796B;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  }

  form {
    background-color: #E0F2F1;
    width: 325px;
    height: 275px;
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    overflow: auto;
    
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
  }

  label {
    position: relitive;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #004D40;
    top: 100px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
  }

  .input-container {
    width: 75%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 45px auto -25px;
  }

  input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    color: #004D40;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #4DB6AC;
    outline: none;
    z-index: 20;
  }

  input[type="text"]:focus ~ label, input[type="text"]:valid ~ label {
    top: -60px;
    background-color: blue;
  }

  input[type="submit"] {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4DB6AC;
    color: #E0F2F1;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border: solid #009688;
    border-width: 0 0 4px 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    outline: none;
  }

  input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #26A69A;
    border: solid #00897B;
    border-width: 0 0 4px 0;
  }

  input[type="submit"]:active {
    background: #009688;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 0 0 0px 0;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <form>
    <div class="input-container">
      <input required type="text" />
      <label>Name</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="input-container">
      <input required type="text" />
      <label>Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-container">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </form>
  ```